# Is there a better way to add a child record using MVC 4 and Entity Framework 5?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-4, entity-framework-5

I am just learning MVC and dealing with its stateless nature in combination with Entity Framework.  My question is, is there a more elegant way of handling the scenario below?

I have two POCO entities:

```
public class Contest
{
    public long ID { get; set; }
    ....   .....
    public ICollection<ContestPrize> Prizes { get; set; }
}

public class ContestPrize
{
    public long ID { get; set; }

    public Contest Contest { get; set; }

}
```

I then have a MVC View that displays the Contest and all the Prizes associated with them.  On that view I have a "Create Prize" link to create a new prize which passes the ID of the contest to the ContestPrize Controller like so:

```
@Html.ActionLink("Create Prize", "Create", "ContestPrizes", new { ContestId = Model.ID }, null)
```

The ContestId is persisted as a hidden field in the form that submits a new prize so that I can retrieve it on create.  The create method on the prize controller is below:

```
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Create(int ParentID, ContestPrize ContestPrize)
    {


        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {

            db.ContestPrizes.Add(ContestPrize);
            db.SaveChanges();
            return RedirectToAction("Index", "Contests", ParentID);
        }

        return View(ContestPrize);
    }
```

This is where I run into some ugliness that I don't like.  Here are the problems:

1. The `ModelState.IsValid` test fails.  This is because the navigation property for the parent is null on the model.  It hasn't been populated.  I can skip the validation on the model and go right to the database but is there a way to populate this without doing #2 below?
2. The parent property isn't populated at this point, but I do have the ParentID that comes in from the hidden form field.  Since everything is stateless, the db object doesn't have the parent object (which is fine).  So, I could perform another database read to get the parent object using the parentID and then do `Parent.Prizes.Add(ContestPrize)` or `ContestPrize.Contest = Parent`.  But I really don't like this because I am making an extra database hit to read the parent, when I have all the information I need to create the child record.

So, is there a way with Entity Framework to just set the ID of the parent and save a child without having to retrieve the parent object?  Or...ideally is there a way using MVC to pre-populate the new model on create with a parent object since I do have the parent before heading into the create views??  How bad would it be to pass around the parent object in ViewData maybe so that it was available?

I can make this work by reloading the parent.  But I want to avoid it if possible.

Thoughts?

**UPDATE:**  Adding the `ContestID` to the ContestPrize POCO and then decorating the navigation property with `[ForeignKey("ContestID")]` as @NSGaga suggested works perfectly and eliminates some of the messy ParentID passing around problems.  The new POCOs looks like this:

```
public class Contest
{
    public long ID { get; set; }
    ....   .....
    public ICollection<ContestPrize> Prizes { get; set; }
}

public class ContestPrize
{
    public long ID { get; set; }

    public long ContestID { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("ContestID")]
    public Contest Contest { get; set; }

}
```

I can eliminate the ParentID being passed and set in the views as a hidden field because data binding in MVC takes care of the ContestID on the new entity (I still have to pass the id into the initial view, but that is all.  It is just bound from there on out).  The new Create action on the Controller looks like this:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Create(ContestPrize ContestPrize)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        db.ContestPrizes.Add(ContestPrize);
        db.SaveChanges();
        return RedirectToAction("Index", "Contests", ContestPrize.ContestID);
    }

    return View(ContestPrize);
}
```

Clean and simple with no mess.  I like it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're using 'code first' (all things suggest), then you can do something like...

```
public class ContestPrize
{
    public long ID { get; set; }

    public long ContestID { get; set; }
    public Contest Contest { get; set; }
}
```

That should create (by convention) and map the ContestID to the FK. In some complicated cases you may need to specify that relationship in the fluent code, but this should suffice normally.

> Then you can just reference the parent by `ContestID` - fill that in -
>   and do `Add`.

That's in rough strokes, let me know if you need more info.

Comment: @NSGaga....thank you!  This worked perfectly.  The only modification I had to make from your suggestion was to decorate my `public Contest Contest { get; set; }` with `[ForeignKey("ContestID")]` and I was up and running.  What's more, I was able to get rid of the the `ParentID` hidden field and just pass the ContestID in which bound right to the new entity...so all that mess goes away.  Thank you so much.

Comment: np - you're welcome Michael. the `public long ContestID { get; set; }` should work alone (the convention is either entity or property name + "Id"). But ForeignKey doesn't hurt, that depends on the specific setup, other configuration you may have.

Comment: That's what I thought too.  But when I did that initially, EF created a new field called "Contest_ID" which was used for the relationship instead of the "ContestID" that I defined.  So I fixed it by forcing the foreignkey.  I don't know if there is something else amiss in my setup that causes that....but adding the data annotation worked and gave me the single field with the correct relationship.

Not that it matters....but for learning purposes any thoughts why it might be creating the separate field by convention and not using the same field?

Comment: Hey Michael - I'm bumping into the exact same problem, and I'm trying to fix it in the same way. But when I pass a new child model, containing the parent ID, to the view, the posted form will lose this parent's ID if I don't explicitely add a hidden field to the form for this ID. You're saying you didn't need that. Any idea how that might be? Or did you mean that you replaced "ParentID" with "ContestID", but still kept the hidden field?

Answer (score 1):

You probably shouldn't be using entities as view models directly. I suggest using something like this:

```
// Entitiy Type
public class ContestPrize { ... }

// ViewModel Type
public class ContestPrizeViewModel { ... }

// In your controller
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Create(int ParentID, ContestPrizeViewModel ContestPrize)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        var entity = db.Create<ContestPrize>();
        entity.ContestID = ParentID;
        entity.Blah = ContestPrize.Blah
        db.ContestPrizes.Add(entity);
        db.SaveChanges();
        return RedirectToAction("Index", "Contests", ParentID);
    }

    return View(ContestPrize);
}
```

This allows you to easily separate your domain logic from your view logic. It may require extra code, but it's a much more robust way of doing things.